# Não permitir mover quando houver apenas uma imagem- bxSlider.js

Tags: jquery, bxslider

Estou utilizando bxslider e o rodo perfeitamente o seguinte código:

```
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.slider').bxSlider({
              auto: true
        });
     });
  </script>
```

Que resulta na movimentação do cartão..

Tenho esta div que dentro dela contem uma imagem .. a inserção da imagem é dinâmica conforme um foreach...

```
<div class="slider">
     <img id="ImgBanner" src="..."> 
</div>
```

Preciso que quando tenha apenas uma imagem, ele não permite arrastar e fique "estático" e quando houver mais de uma imagem, funcionar normalmente a opção de arrastar.

Experimentei utilizar o seguinte código e não resultou em nada:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.slider').bxSlider({
          auto: ($("#ImgBanner").length > 1) ? true: false,
          pager: ($("#ImgBanner").length > 1) ? true: false,
         controls: false
   });
 });
```

Comment: o trecho `$("#ImgBanner").length` retorna a quantidade da forma correta?

Comment: Faltava a div que englobava, obrigado por sua resposta.

Answer (score 0):

A solução foi esta, onde verifico a quantidade de imagens e crio um operador ternário conforme o resultado, habilitando ou não o touch:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.slider').bxSlider({
                auto: true,
                touchEnabled:($('.slider #ImgBanner').length > 1) ? true : false,
            });
   });
```